# Override/update af variables value in proc sql using case when statement

Tags: sql, sas, overriding, case-when

I want to left join a variable from an "old" dataset to a "new" dataset.
The UFORM variable has the values 25 or .. 
If the left join gives me the value of ., I want to replace it with the value 0. Can't I update the value of the UFORM-variable in the following sql statement in stead of making the UFORM2 variable?

The statement below works, but I'd rather not make the UFORM2-variable.

```
proc sql;
   create table new as
   select X.*, Z.UFORM , case when Z.UFORM eq . then 0 else Z.UFORM end as UFORM2
   from old X
   left join info Z
   on X.value1 = Z.value1
   and X.value2 = Z.value2;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
proc sql;
   create table new as
   select X.*, coalesce(Z.UFORM, 0) as UFROM
   from old X left join
        info Z
        on X.value1 = Z.value1 and
           X.value2 = Z.value2;
quit;
```